# uconv - Does the -x option define a transliterator or a transform?

Tags: unicode, icu

The [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv) for `uconv` say:

> -x transliteration
> Run the given transliteration on the transcoded Unicode data, and use the transliterated data as input for the transcoding to the the destination encoding.

It also includes the following two examples:

> `echo '\u30ab' | uconv -x 'hex-any; any-name'`
>
> `uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -x '::nfkc; [:Cc:] >; ::katakana-hiragana;'`

The first example points towards the `-x` option defining a ["compound transform"](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Using-Transliterators) but the second example points to it being a ["rule-based transliterator"](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Rule-Based-Transliterators).

This is exacerbated by the fact that many of ICU's provided examples ([1](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Overview), [2](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Compound-IDs)) don't work:

```
$ echo "Example" | uconv -f UTF8 -t UTF8 -x 'NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC;'
Couldn't create transliteration "NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC;": U_MISSING_OPERATOR, line 0, offset 0.

$ echo "Example" | uconv -f UTF8 -t UTF8 -x '[:Latin:]; NFKD; Lower; Latin-Katakana;'
Couldn't create transliteration "[:Latin:]; NFKD; Lower; Latin-Katakana;": U_MISSING_OPERATOR, line 0, offset 0.
```

But some examples ([1](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Filtered-IDs), [2](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Compound-IDs)) work just fine:

```
$ echo "Example" | uconv -f UTF8 -t UTF8 -x '[aeiou] Upper'
ExAmplE

$ echo "Example" | uconv -f UTF8 -t UTF8 -x 'NFKD; Lower; Latin-Katakana;'
エクサンプレ
```

---

**So what the heck does `-x` define?**

---

The plot thickens!  It looks like `uconv` chokes on predefined character classes that aren't in a transform rule.

Regular character classes:

```
$ echo "Example" | uconv -f UTF8 -t UTF8 -x '[a-zA-Z] Upper'
EXAMPLE

$ echo "Example" | uconv -f UTF8 -t UTF8 -x ':: [a-zA-Z] Upper;'
EXAMPLE
```

Predefined character classes:

```
$ echo "Example" | uconv -f UTF8 -t UTF8 -x '[:alpha:] Upper'
Couldn't create transliteration "[:alpha:] Upper": U_MISSING_OPERATOR, line 0, offset 0.

$ echo "Example" | uconv -f UTF8 -t UTF8 -x ':: [:alpha:] Upper;'
EXAMPLE
```

Just in case, here's the version of `uconv` I'm using:

```
$ uconv --version
uconv v2.1  ICU 58.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It does different things depending on what you pass.

The excerpt below is formatted code from [`uconv.cpp`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ICU/ICU-57149.0.1/icuSources/extra/uconv/uconv.cpp.auto.html).  `translit` is the value of the `-x` argument.

```
UnicodeString str(translit), pestr;

/* Create from rules or by ID as needed. */

parse.line = -1;

if (uprv_strchr(translit, ':') || uprv_strchr(translit, '>') ||
    uprv_strchr(translit, '<') || uprv_strchr(translit, '>')) {
  t = Transliterator::createFromRules(UNICODE_STRING_SIMPLE("Uconv"), str,
                                      UTRANS_FORWARD, parse, err);
} else {
  t = Transliterator::createInstance(UnicodeString(translit, -1, US_INV),
                                     UTRANS_FORWARD, err);
}
```

And `createFromRules` further differs in what it creates based on the input:

> Returns a `Transliterator` object constructed from
>   the given rule string.  This will be a RuleBasedTransliterator,
>   if the rule string contains only rules, or a
>   CompoundTransliterator, if it contains ID blocks, or a
>   NullTransliterator, if it contains ID blocks which parse as
>   empty for the given direction.

Comment: Dang, so my suspicions were correct.  As long as the input has a `:` it's being parsed differently.  Shouldn't be too difficult to tweak it.